# Get Bash MINGW32 doesn't except array length with surrounding Parenthesis

Tags: bash, mingw32

I have strange behavior with git (that comes with source tree installation) mingw32 bash.

Say I have see the surrounding parenthesis the array:

```
for ((i=0; i<(${#list_array[@]}); ++i)); do

done
```

I'm getting this error:

```
./test.sh: line 1595: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./test.sh: line 1595: `        done'
```

But when I remove the surrounding parenthesis like this:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#list_array[@]}; ++i)); do

done
```

Everything is working fine, as result I have cross platform problem
as this script run on Linux and now I need it to run under windows.
I really what to know the root cause to this.

This is my bash version in mingw32:

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(2)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical. Your error-message doesn't seem to be anywhere near the parentheses. I'm wondering if maybe the issue has to with Windows vs. non-Windows line endings somehow, and your file-editor incidentally fixed that when you made that change? (Just a guess.)

Comment: By the way, even if your analysis really is correct, then that still doesn't give you a cross-platform problem. The parentheses aren't necessary; you can remove them from both versions of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the `"syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'"` indicates a DOS line ending or other extraneous character in your array causing problem.